# How do I access localStorage in store of NuxtJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get a value from localStorage to determine the value of a variable in store. I remember trying something similar with vuejs about a year ago and it seemed to work. I also have no issues with this on Reactjs. But for some reason i keep getting this error when doing the same in Nuxt

[image]

[image]

this is my <kbd>user.js</kbd> file

```
export const state = () => ({
  isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem('userDetails')
})

export const mutations = {
  login(state) {
    state.isLoggedIn = true;
  },
  logout(state) {
    window.localStorage.clear()
    state.isLoggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

am i approaching this problem wrong? or is this not supposed to work? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing ssr?

Comment: I believe so. Do I have to recreate the app as PWA for this to work? but then i'd be giving up the ssr. Is there another workaround? or recreating as PWA is the only way around this.

Comment: @Roj I added a new answer to get around the SSR problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
isLoggedIn: process.server ? '' : !!localStorage.getItem('userDetails')
```

The problem is that you try to access the localstorage while nuxt is on the server side. you need to check with `process.server` if you are on the server side or not. It returns either true or false.

I didnt tested it but with this ternary operator it should work.

Here: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/

Comment: no error this time. It seems the problem has to do with ssr.  I'll probably have to redo the whole project and disable ssr. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Roj no error means you had access to the localstorage. well you can go to `nuxt.config.js` and rename `mode: "universal"` to `mode: "spa"` if you want to disable ssr and only go with client side

Answer (score 6):

When you use SSR you don't have access to the browser storage.

To do a workaround, you can dispatch an action on the mounted component hook.

```
mounted() {

 if(!process.client) return;
 const savedData = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
 if(savedData){
    this.$store.commit('myMutation',savedData)
}
}
```

Comment: thanks I'll try this. is there a way to commit on my mutation on the base app itself?

Comment: well you should wrap it in an if statement `if(process.client) {}`

Comment: Roj, you can do in the same way, in the mounted() hook. @ifaruki, yes, mine was just a way to indicate the path to go, but you right. I edited my answer

Comment: that wasnt that what i meant. it will throw an error again `localStorage` is not defined. you need to wrap everything in `if(process.client)`

Answer (score 1):

In nuxt3, you can just use `useCookie` to persist small amounts of data. https://v3.nuxtjs.org/examples/composables/use-cookie#usecookie

Comment: what about in nuxt v 2.15 ?

Comment: page removed unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

For the people coming here from Google, I wrote a plugin that will allow you to do this without having to disable SSR.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-vuex-localstorage-sync

Answer (score -1):

I can see that you have not set any localstorage. Please set localstorage by

> localstorage.setItem()

Comment: this is not the issue